# TypeScript: Allow types as parameter of function that contain certain keys

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, typeguards

Let´s assume I have two interfaces.

```
interface AppleReport {
    name: string,
    color: string,
    age: string
}

interface BananaReport {
    name: string,
    color: string,
    amount: number,
}
```

Now I define a function. I want this function to take every type that has a **name** key and a **color** key.

```
cosnt doSth = (value: **TODO**) => {
    // do sth with *value* that contains *name* and *color*
}
```

I know, that I could create an interface

```
interface dummyInterface {
    name: string,
    color: string,
}
```

and let the *AppleReport* and *BananaReport* extend this, but I would like to do all of the logic in the function type definiton.

Any ideas?

Comment: `(value: **TODO**)` -> `(value: dummyInterface)`?

Comment: Then I would still need to create a dummyInterface.

Comment: No other option?

Comment: You can also define it inline but it's usually just clutter. And *typically* if you need such a thing once, you'd probably find use of it again. An interface is more reusable. Still, inlining the interface would also work.

Comment: Are you trying to just write an anonymous object type like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mMxrdN)?  Or are you trying to have the compiler compute the required type from `AppleReport` and `BananaReport`?  You could just use a union like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w66KDw), which only lets you access common members.  Or are you looking for something else?  Let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do

```
cosnt doSth = (value: { name : string, color : string } ) => {
    // do sth with *value* that contains *name* and *color*
}
```

but This looks messy and would recommend going with the way you do not want to and create an interface and then extend the other 2 interfaces from it.

or if you dont want to extends the other interfaces you can just use the interface type as the type to pass in and not extend. It will still work as long as the members exist.

```
interface NameAndColor {
  name: string,
  color: string,
}

interface AppleReport {
  name: string,
  color: string,
  age: string
}

interface BananaReport {
  name: string,
  color: string,
  amount: number,
}

const doSth = (value: NameAndColor) => {
  // do sth with *value* that contains *name* and *color*
}

let obj = { name : "myName", color : "myColor"};
doSth( obj );
```

But really the best way is to have your interfaces extend in my opinion.